ggsurvplot cuts off picture at xlim
I created the following survival curve using ggsurvplot with below code:
library(survminer)
library(survival)

set.seed(2025)
fakedata <- data.frame(time = rexp(20, rate = log(2)/6), event = sample(x = c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = T, prob = c(0.25, 0.75)))
fakesurv <- survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ 1, data = fakedata)

ggsurvplot(fakesurv, ylab = "Progression-free survival (%)", 
           xlab = "Time since first treatment (months)", 
           xlim = c(0,18), break.x.by = 3, conf.int = F,  
           risk.table = "nrisk_cumcensor",  surv.scale = "percent", 
           tables.y.text = F, legend.title = element_blank(), 
           legend.labs = "All patients", axes.offset = F)

As you can see there are two things wrong with the picture: the time points (3, 6, etc) don't match up between the x-axis of the curve and the risk table and the entire picture is cut off at 18 months so that the number at risk at that timepoint is unreadable.
I was only going to ask about the second problem: the original picture, of which this is a recreation with fake data, only had the second problem and not the first. However now I also want to know (of course) where the first problem is coming from.
Regarding the second problem: it goes away if change the axes.offset command to T. However at that point the axes no longer cross at (0, 0). (We wanted them to do that, that's why we have the `axes.offset = F in the code.)


This kind of problem would typically be fixed in ggplot by modifying the theme element plot.margin. However, ggsurvplot works a little differently, since a ggsurvplot object is actually two ggplots in a special type of list with its own drawing method that stitches the plot and table together. As a result, you cannot just modify the theme elements by adding theme() calls to the end of your plot code.
To compound matters, the theme options available in the call to ggsurvplot are actually a little limited. This is often the case with functions that use wrappers to call ggplot; what you gain in ease-of-use you lose in ease-of-customisation.
I would probably just create and store the object, then reach in and change the bits that I want modified:
p <- ggsurvplot(fakesurv, ylab = "Progression-free survival (%)", 
           xlab = "Time since first treatment (months)", 
           xlim = c(0,18), break.x.by = 3, conf.int = FALSE,  
           risk.table = "nrisk_cumcensor",  surv.scale = "percent", 
           tables.y.text = FALSE, legend.title = element_blank(), 
           legend.labs = "All patients", axes.offset = FALSE) 

p$plot$theme$plot.margin <- ggplot2::margin(10, 50, 10, 20)
p$table$theme$plot.margin <- ggplot2::margin(10, 50, 10, 30)
p$table$coordinates$clip <- "off"

p


